# No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker

Tags: flutter

image_picker: ^0.6.7+4
No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker

Comment: it was working previously, but its not working now, even most of the plug in like multi_image_picker, google_sign_in also behaving same.

Comment: there is a solution for the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64409367/flutter-missingpluginexception-no-implementation-found-for-method-pickimage-o

Answer (score 0):

[sobhan ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13892613/sobhan-ghosh) this package has been updated `pickImage` and `pickVideo` APIs are now `getImage` and `getVideo`.
For more info visit package [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker#call-the-new-methods) link

Comment: Now im getting this issue : Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker

Comment: No improvement @Hakiza

Comment: What's snippet code are you using? Am using this version and i've no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Future getImage() async{
 var photo = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);//".gallery" if you want to take image from gallery
 setState(() {
   _image = photo;//_image is the image file where your image is going to store
 });
}
```

It may help you