# Flutter - MissingPluginException (No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to pick an image from the gallery using image_picker package and this error keeps persisting no matter what. **Solutions iv'e already tried**:

1. Terminating, Cleaning, Rerunning, Restarting IDE, and Restarting PC
2. Changing compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion
3. Downgrading the package version

```
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker)
E/flutter ( 2928): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157:7)
E/flutter ( 2928): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2928): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:12)
```

The function i use to get the image:

```
void getPicture() async{

    final picker = ImagePicker();
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    _image = File(pickedFile.path);
    _picLink = await dbOnlineInstance.uploadProfilePic(_image, authInstance.firebaseAuthInstance.currentUser.email);

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Do some packages conflict disable others for example? My installed packages:

```
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  splashscreen:
  provider:
  route_transitions:
  flutter_vector_icons:
  simple_animations:
  supercharged:
  animated_background:
  sqflite:
  path:
  toggle_switch:
  firebase_auth:
  firebase_core:
  cloud_firestore:
  image_picker:
  shared_preferences:
  cached_network_image:
  firebase_storage:
  google_sign_in:
  flutter_facebook_auth:
  draggable_widget:
  enum_to_string:
  stacked:
  auto_route:
  stacked_services:
  get_it:
  injectable:
```

Or is it a problem of permissions? Although this package does not require permissions and the error itself isn't permission-related.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the editor.

Comment: This mostly happens to me when I add a new dependency. The solution is easy - just terminate the app & then run again. This should solve your issue.

Comment: Ravi, this is the first thing i said I've tried, thank you though. Sagar, i've just restarted the editor, the whole pc, still nothing makes a difference so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yeah, as i expected. After a lot of testing, it turned out that the package **flutter_facebook_auth** (when not configured) conflicts with **image_picker**. I don't know what this package has to do with disabling the image_picker plugin and actually making it missing like it wasn't installed.

If you plan to use flutter_facebook_auth, then make sure you don't just put it in the pubspec.yaml and **configure your AndroidManifest and Strings.xml** even if you're not planning to use the package it at the time and just putting it for the sake of installing-all-packages-at-once.

Comment: Finally, this save my day!

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar to yours, but mine was between **flutter_facebook_auth** and **sqflite**.

I received (after executing the **"flutter run"**):
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException (No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin)

The solution was after reading **@Ismaeil Ghouneim** reply, **thanks man**!

I did all the configuration following this tutorial here: https://facebook.meedu.app/#/ and everything went back to work!

Comment: Please don't add _"thanks"_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](/help/why-vote).