# Flutter problems after publishing: "No implementation found for method"

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I've published my first app, builtup using Flutter, Dart and Android Studio.
Some functionalities working well in debug mode(even running app in "Release mode" on AS), **after publishing** doesn't work anymore.
This is my code:

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    image_picker: ^0.6.7+12
    url_launcher : ^5.7.8
```

Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

launch function:

```
  _launchURL(url) async {
    await launch(url);
  }
```

Running  the app in debug mode, they come out these messages:

> E/flutter (13880): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)]
> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found
> for method launch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher)

> E/flutter (16247): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)]
> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found
> for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker)

I've found out only post like "make flutter clean and rerun the IDE", but the problem is not on my IDE, but on the user after downloading the app.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you add the required permissions in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Hi adit, thank you for the answer, I edit my code with the manifest.

Comment: I think, that your solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64409367/flutter-missingpluginexception-no-implementation-found-for-method-pickimage-o